# How to represent NSNumber with scientific notation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I use [NSNumber numberWithDouble:] method to form my NSNumber. However, since some of the values might be large, I want to know if there is a way to tell NSNumber to represent itself with the scientific notation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html). They allow for higher precision than `NSNumber`, and [support scientific notation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithMantissa%3aexponent%3aisNegative%3a) and other features.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the number into as string and use the [scientific print formatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) `%e`, or `%E`

I say this because there is no point in trying to get the NSNumber to format itself because it is only an object wrapper around a value. When you want to present the number, then treat it as a string and use the NSString methods to show the value in the way that you want.